# How to dynamically import css with backbone?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm developing a app, using backbone, underscore, and jquerymobile. Following jqmobile's way, I have an index page which loads every visited page in special `div`s tags, flagged with the attribute `data-role="page"`. For each page, i have its corresponding style file (or code snippet embedded in a `style` html tag). My problem is that the names of my *stylable* stuff started to collide. Other thing is that I would not like unnecessary style files loaded for each page. Is there any way of dynamically import only the required css for the current page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am accomplishing exactly what you ask using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and the [RequireCSS](https://github.com/VIISON/RequireCSS) plugin.

Here is a snippet from one of my views:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/company/form',
  'text!templates/company/company.html',
  'css!../../../css/company/company',
], function($, _, Backbone, Form, pageTemplate) {

  var Page = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
  });

  return Page;

});
```

Line 7, `'css!../../../css/company/company'` is where the css file becomes a requirement for loading this view.

Once the `company.css` stylesheet is loaded, it's in the browser even when other "pages" load because there are no actual page refreshes. Thus I have my main page views toggle a class on the `<html>` element:

```
// remove any old route-* classes existing on the html element
$('html').removeClassRegEx(/^route-.*/);
// add in the company's top-level class name
$('html').addClass('route-company');
```

And all my page-specific styles for the `company` page are scoped to the `.route-company` class.

You can find the [jQuery plugin removeClassRegEx here](http://www.websanova.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-remove-class-by-regular-expression).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is with **jquery** (which you 90% are already using with backbone), and its `load` or `get` ajax functions, or whatever, plus callbacks.

Then you can call such functions from your backbone app if you need to, and simply inject that css inside `<style>` tags into your document, as a template.

Or I think there are also specialized jquery functions.

Another way I can think of doing that would be with **require.js** and it's plugins (it has `text` plugin, I believe, which will also enable you to load your javascript templates).